# C++ MPI Iprobe unitialized local variable 'buf' used

Tags: c++, malloc, mpi, new-operator

I'm new to C++ and MPI. Got the task and read a lot. I`m still confident that I wrote everything correctly, but still unable to execute without any errors. My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
int myid, numprocs, **buf, source, i; 
    int message[3] = { 0, 1, 2 };
    int myrank, data = 2002, count, TAG = 0;
    MPI_Status status; 
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL); 
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);

    if (myrank == 0) {
        MPI_Send(&data, 1, MPI_INT, 2, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else if (myrank == 1) {
        MPI_Send(&message, 3, MPI_INT, 2, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else {
        MPI_Probe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        source = status.MPI_SOURCE; 
        MPI_Get_count(&status, MPI_INT, &count);

        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            //buf[i] = new int[count * sizeof(int)];
             buf[i] = (int *)malloc(count * sizeof(int));
        } 
        MPI_Recv(&buf[0], count, MPI_INT, source, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            printf("received: %d\n", buf[i]);
        }
    }
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Errors:

```
Error   C4700   uninitialized local variable 'buf' used
```

I don't get why it wants it to be initialized. I gave the memory space and just want to fill it further. It seems I don`t unserstand some C++ simple operation or smth. Initializing something like

```
int **buf = nullptr;
```

Also tried:

```
buf[i] = new int[count * sizeof(int)];
```

didn`t make any difference. Please give me a hint.

Comment: `buf` is indeed used uninitialized.

Comment: declare `int * buf` and then `buf = (int *)malloc(count * sizeof(int)`. As a matter of style/taste, you can `MPI_Recv(buf, ...)`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet thank you so m uch for the answer. Now it gives me ```Error C4703 potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'buf' used```. It seems it is because it`s inside of "else", but how could I do it earlier if I haven`t known the "count" variable value before?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I got it to work wit no errors with ```buf = new int[count * sizeof(int)];``` and ```MPI_Recv(buf, count, MPI_INT, source, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);```, but now the application simply freezes and gives no results.

Comment: I assume you started 3 MPI tasks. rank 2 should receive two messages (from ranks 0 and 1), but it currently only receive one.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet yes, you're write. If I use 2 proccesses and send only &data or only &message it works correctly. But it is not able to receive more than 1 message and just freezes. Increasing number of proccesses didn't work as well and they run every time in different order. I`m confused.

Comment: by design, ranks 3 and above do not send nor are sent any message. So if you plan to run 3 or more MPI tasks, replace `else` with `eise if (myrank == 2)` otherwise `MPI_Probe()` will hang forever.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet ok, I got it, thank you so much. But it still hangs.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I've just wrapped the whole ```else if(myrank==2)``` in the for loop for i<=2 and it successfully received all the messages! Thank you so much for your time and efforts!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you need check value of count.

Example (hint(?))

```
count = 0;
```

And again try

Comment: This is neither what the warning describes, nor an error in the program since count is being initalized through GetCount. This is about buf not being initialized, as  the comments already suggest.